# Passing array into simple_query() causes mysql error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following query:

```
$this->db->simple_query("UPDATE account 
                            SET balance = ? 
                               WHERE user = ?",array($balance,$user))
```

However, it gives me an error near `? WHERE user = ?`. What would be the proper way of passing an array to the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [simple_query docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html)

> It DOES NOT return a database result set, nor does it set the query
> timer, or compile bind data

The proper way would be to user `query` instead.

Comment: In other words: it's too simple to use prepared statements :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$columns = array('balance'=>$balance,'user'=>$user);
$this->db->where(array('user' => 'your_value'));
$result = $this->db->update('account', $columns);
```

or use

```
$this->db->query()
```